# How to group fields and place in seperate tabs/local tasks?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to group fields and create different tabs/local tasks for them with their own dedicated pages. How can I do that?

I found one module that looked promising, but also that one has bug on installation: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_ui

What other options do I have?

I tried ask the question before but it was mistakenly marked as duplicated so open a new question to allow for answers:
[How to group fields and place in seperate tabs?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251396/how-to-group-fields-and-place-in-seperate-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You can create local tasks for this in yml. Local tasks are what appear as tabs when viewing an Entity. You can code the tabs yourself. There's not much to it: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks

Answer from Kevin here:
[How to group fields and place in seperate tabs?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251396/how-to-group-fields-and-place-in-seperate-tabs?noredirect=1#comment307626_251396)